# Wrong URLs in Entities section of Tweet object

Tags: api, twitter, tweets, twython

I'm extracting URLs from tweets using Twitter APIs with a Python lib named Twython. I use [home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline) API and look at `entities` to search for URLs.
Normally, the links in `entities` are correct. However, in some cases, the links are wrong. For example, this is a tweet from account `@WWF-Philippines`:
[image]

When I hover the cursor over the highlighted link, it shows `shortened_url1` (I cannot put here because Stackoverflow doesn't allow) on the status bar. If I click on the link, it opens an external [article](http://www.wwf.org.ph/stories/seven-leave-no-trace-lnt-principles). However, if I use Twitter API to query the corresponding tweet, here is the tweet I get:

```
Need a guide to properly enjoy the great outdoors while minimizing human impact? This list is for you!\xe2\x80\xa6 shortened_url2
```

You can see the shortened_url2 here is different from the true link (shortened_url1) shown when hovering the cursor. If I follow the shortened_url2, it opens the same tweet. The link in the `entities` part is the same with this wrong link (shortened_url2).

So what's wrong with Twitter APIs here?
Thanks.

Comment: how about posting some code you've written?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at the *old* version of the entities.

The Twitter status is - https://twitter.com/WWF_Philippines/status/869027117652033536

Calling `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/869027117652033536.json` from the API gives us the following entities:

```
"truncated": true,
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "urls": [{
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/UatUzmm9re",
        "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/869027117652033536",
        "display_url": "twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/8\u2026",
        "indices": [104, 127]
    }]
},
```

Notice at the top it says `"truncated": true,`?

Recently Twitter changed how it displays tweets and how they're represented in the API - see https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

You need to add `?tweet_mode=extended` to the end of your query.  That will get you back:

```
"truncated": false,
"display_text_range": [0, 126],
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "urls": [{
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/BgKxmFzrQc",
        "expanded_url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/7LNTPrinciples",
        "display_url": "bit.ly\/7LNTPrinciples",
        "indices": [103, 126]
    }],
```

Which contains the data you want.

Comment: Thanks, it might be the cause. However, Twython doesn't support the parameter 'tweet_mode' yet.

Comment: It does. See https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/430 - you need to add something like `tweet = twitter.show_status(id=tweet_id, tweet_mode='extended')`